# Array não está como array

Tags: php, array

Estou com o seguinte código

```
<?php
while($data = $QuerySearch->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                $js[] = $data;


        }

            $r = array();
            $arr = array();

        foreach($js as $k=>$v){

            foreach($v as $col=>$c){

                $arr[] = $c;
            }

            array_push($r, $arr);



        }

        $r = array_map('htmlentities', $arr);

        if(isset($r)){

            echo 'Existe<br>';

            if(is_array($arr)){

                echo 'Tb existe';
            }else{

                echo 'nao existe arr';
            }
        }else{

            echo 'nao existe';
        }

        echo print_r($r);
?>
```

Como vocês podem ver, o array está sendo formado, só que ele não exibe o array. Quando eu coloco um `echo` no lugar de `arr[]` ele exibe normalmente os dados, agora eu coloco um  `echo json_encode($arr);`  ele fica vazio, e nas verificações que eu fiz acima exibe assim:

```
Existe
Não existe arr
```

Ou seja, existe `$arr[]` mas ele diz que não é um `array()`

Comment: E essa linha aqui: `$arr = '';` no final do `foreach`, ela ta convertendo `$arr` em `string` não?

Comment: @Cahe Realmente, só que ao executar 1 vez o loop, preciso que tipo, zere o indice pq vai criar + arrays. para ficar tudo assim arr[0] => dados, arr[1] =>dados... Eu coloquei $arr[] = array(); exibe um array vazio

Comment: @Cahe eu dei print_r($arr) e ele me exibe todos os dados, mas coloco json_encode ele não exibe nada.

Comment: O que quer fazer com `$r`? Não devia ser o `$r` que você checa no if/else em baixo? Essa linha `$arr = '';` está a apagar o `$arr`, tire-a.

Comment: @Sergio fiz tudo o que você disse e quando dou `echo json_encode($r)` ele não aparece, agora se ponho `print_r($r)`ele aparece os dados que preciso

Comment: E se fizer `var_dump($r);` o que aparece?

Comment: @Sergio aparece as mesmas coisas que o `print_r` . O estranho é que os outros `json_encode()` funciona corretamente, só que eu uso assim `json_encode(array('indice'=>'valor'));` envez de `json_encode($r);`

Comment: Aí devia ter uma resposta tipo `{"indice":"valor"}`. Pode colocar o código relacionado com esse `json_encode`, assim vai dar para perceber como está a fazer. Agora não existe nenhum `json_encode` na pergunta...

Comment: Htmlentities também não suporta acentuação sem passar os paramentos de codificação ISO 8859... E um detalhe, favor não modificar o código original com erro na pergunta, se for o caso acrescente o corrigido abaixo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defina o charset na conexão com `utf8`.

> PHP diz:
>   Esta função funciona somente com dados com codificação UTF-8

```
$db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Comment: o seu está dando certo, só que ele só exibe o último array porque ele faz um loop de uma lista e os indices são iguais e eu precisava que ficassem tipo assim `array('0'=>dados1, '1'=>dados2)` onde dados1 e dados2 são o indice e valor que retornou dos registros

Comment: A unica coisa que passei, foi como arrumar os dados para o json rodar, talvez o seu array esteja quebrando em algum ponto. Vou testar aqui com um array qualquer

Comment: como não está separando se é a lista1, lista2 então os indices dele fica numerados de 1 a 44 sendo q era 1-22 e do 23-44 por isso de mudar o indice do array principal

Comment: Comente a seguinte linha `$arr = '';` ela está no final do `foreach` e sempre esta zerando. Quando comentei o resultado foi: `Existe`, `Tb existe`

Comment: Na verdade já foi tirada essa linha.. agora está `
    $r = array();
    $arr = array();

   foreach($js as $k=>$v){

    foreach($v as $col=>$c){

     $arr[] = $c;
    }

    array_push($r, $arr);



   }

   $r = array_map('htmlentities', $arr);`

Comment: Então atualize o codigo na sua questão para facilitar

Comment: Pronto, atualizei.

Comment: Testei seu codigo como está e o retorno foi `Existe, Tb existe`. Perceba que `$r` e `$arr` são a mesma coisa, não tem como cair na negação do if.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16146/discussion-between-papa-charlie-and-alisson-acioli).

Comment: Show! Era isso mesmo, a codificação. Só foi mudar e deu tudo certo! Obrigado @PapaCharlie

Comment: Disponha, depois dê uma olhada nas codificações do DB para manter um padrão

Comment: Tudo bem, pode dx.